# WooCommerce JS issue on checkout

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a big problem with my site. I`m using latest version of WooCommerce (2.1.12) but there is a problem with checkout. Checkout works if I turn off email notifications for new order... But if I turn this options on (WooCommerce - Email - New Order) I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of null checkout.min.js?ver=2.1.12:1
```

I try to switch to default theme, turn off all plugins...Nothing work. Only if I turn off email notifications but this is not a solution for me :(

I really need help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem, the checkout does fail in an AJAX call..

Try to look the response of the AJAX call with Google Chrome.
Open the Developer tool before trying to check out. Then try to checkout.

Then in the network section of the developer tool, click on the last checkout/admin-ajax.php call and click Response on the right tab. 
You will be able to see what the calls as returned, maybe and error is triggered and corrupt the json return.

You could try to set 
    error_reporting(0);
in your wp-config.php  to see if its because of a notice or a warning.